# Struts 2 : Adding a a Custom Interface for Actions

Tags: struts2

I was thinking about adding a new Interface (like validationAware, etc.) for sturts 2. The methods of the interface would be methods that sets specific parameters that has to be present inside the request.

For example, consider this Interface :

```
    public interface MyCustomInterfaceForActions {

        /**
         * Set a specific parameter into the request 
         */
        public void setMyParameter1InRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String myParameter);

        /**
         * Sets another specific parameter into the request 
         */
        public void setSecondParamInRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String myParameter);

    }
```

The thing is that I don't want to have to "call" the method "setParameterInRequest" in "execute" methods of each actions that implements that interface.

Also, I want to "force" the actions to set specific parameters into the request.

Is there a way to do that without having to call the "set" methods inside all "executes" methods of my actions? For example, can I extend a struts' "actionExecutor" (I made that name up) and change it's behavior to check if the class implements "MyCustomInterfaceForActions" and call the "set" methods if it's the case?

Or better yet, just check to see if the interface is implemented and just add those parameters to the request anyway, without having to implement methods?

Comment: What's the actual goal? As Shivan says, there's already `Preparable`. What do you want to put into the request, and why?

Comment: The final goal is because I have a light box to select something specific that can be displayed by some pages (actions). This light box needs some specific parameters into the request to be displayed correctly. Maybe an interceptor would be better than.. mmm

Comment: If the parameters are action-specific, use `Preparable`. If it's across the application, use an interceptor. Depending on how the parameters are accessed, they can also just be action properties retrieved using JSP EL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use the [Preparable](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.2.1/struts2-core-2.2.1-javadoc.jar!/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Preparable.html), interface. This way you can do your initialization in the prepare() method?

Comment: Well, the thing is that I want to force the actions to initialize some specific parameters to the request. For example :

setMyParameter1InRequest(...)
setMySecondParamInRequest(...)

Maybe that my example wasn't that good (will edit)

Comment: Well, if your Action implements ServletRequestAware and Preparable, and then in your prepare() method you add your code to initialize the request stuff, you'll be sure that that action will execute that code automatically. You can but it in a base action class, and have actions that need to do this inherit from that base action...

Comment: Thanks for the input! It made me come to the conclusion that I needed an interceptor ;)